# Tensorflow 1.10+: passing epoch to estimator input_fn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

A `tf.estimator` `input_fn`'s signature might look something like this:

```py
def input_fn(files:list, params:dict):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files)
                .map(lambda record: parse_record_fn(record))

    if params['mode'] == 'train':
        # train specific things
    # ...
```

Such a definition allows for one to then construct all of their `input_fn`s as follows:

```py
train_fn = lambda: input_fn(files['training_set'], {**params, **{"mode": "train"}})
valid_fn = lambda: input_fn(files['validation_set'], {**params, **{"mode": "eval"}})
test_fn  = lambda: input_fn(files['test_set'],  {**params, **{"mode": "test"}})


train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_fn, ...)
eval_spec  = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=valid_fn,  ...)
```

My question is how would one alter the `input_fn` signature to allow for epoch based variation. I understand this may introduce a bottle neck, but it would be nice if  I could do something like:

```py
def input_fn(...):
    # see above

    epoch = params["epoch"]
    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        # modify or make a new dataset

    # ...
    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

The key is to make sure the `input_fn` is still compatible with:

```py
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any option that provides the `epoch` number as a parameter as such.

That said, an epoch is, by definition, a feature of the input function so we should just be able to handle everything inside the input function rather than having access to the training parameter at all. So i think you can probably achieve what you need to with a little bit of fiddling around.

For example if I have 2 datasets: `ds1` and `ds2` say and want to use `ds1` whenever "epoch" number is not divisible by 100 then I can just create a new dataset by doing something like:

```py
dataset = ds1.repeat(99).concatenate(ds2)
```

as datasets are lazily loaded by default i dont need to worry about memory implications (I'm not loading 100 times as much data into memory).

Obviously this does have implications for the size of the dataset though so you'd need to think about the strategy for steps between eval ops/callbacks etc but that should be easy enough to tweak.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Unfortunately that doesn't quite work in my case. My input function has some _required_ per-processing that happens at runtime. So the data is loaded, every _n_ epochs some randomness is applied to the data, the data is then modified based on this and then the `(features, labels)` tuples / `dataset` are returned. This is required because calculating all of this up front is too great of a cost.